# Not enough memory to run this program Error message in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I'm using a desktop with 4GB memory (3.4 GB usable) on Intel Core-i5-2310 CPU, 32-bit Windows 10 Pro. Some times I get the error message like "Not enough memory to run this application" when I start an application. When I see Task manager, the total memory occupied by all the processes comes to 1.2 GB. And it shows around 54% memory. If that is the case the total usable memory should be only around 2.22GB (= 1.2 x 100/54). But the total usable memory is 3.4 GB. Why is Windows not using that available memory of 3.4 GB for running the application?

Comment: Have you disabled the swap file?

Comment: Perhaps not disabled, but is the size of the `pagefile` smaller than the total size of the memory?

Comment: It was around 1330 MB. In the mean time, I went through some articles in the internet and as per some suggestions that I came across, I increased the Paging file size for C Drive to 5000 MB (under Custom size, for both Initial size and Maximum size). Will this be enough?
Also, I have some more questions on this:-
1. The application that I executed resides in G drive. Does it mean that I should I set the page file in G drive?
2. Why does the system say "insufficient memory" when the total occupied memory as seen in the Task manager is only 54%?

Comment: Ideally, you want the pagefile settings configured to let Windows manage the size automatically so that it can increase it automatically when it needs to.